# How to make an infinite JS Carousel ( infinity problem)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Trying to make an infinite carousel, which would center at a position of my choosing.
the carousel should loop around, i implemented the effect only to one side at the moment my main issue is that the transition is visible.

the effect i need to achieve is when you click the carousel the loop is infinite but you cannot see the flickering from one end to the other, im relatively new to web development so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
      <div class="content__bottom">
    <div class="service__block" data-name="instagram" data-order="1">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">אינסטגרם</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="facebook" data-order="2">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">פייסבוק</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="youtube" data-order="3">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-youtube"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">יוטיוב</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="twitch" data-order="4">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-twitch"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">טוויץ</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="twitter" data-order="5">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-twitter"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">טוויטר</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="pinterest" data-order="6">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-pinterest"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">פינטרסט</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="soundcloud" data-order="7">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">סאונדקלאוד</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="spotify" data-order="8">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-spotify"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">ספוטיפי</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="telegram" data-order="9">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-telegram-plane"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">טלגרם</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="service__block" data-name="tumblr" data-order="10">
      <i class="service__block--icon fab fa-tumblr"></i>
      <h5 class="service__block--title">טאמבלר</h5>
      <i class="service__block--arrow fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; // 1rem = 10px, 10px/16px = 62.5%
}

body {
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  // overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content__bottom {
  margin-top: 3%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2% 2%;
    display: flex;
}

.service__block {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      width: 210px;
      height: 200px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 3rem 5rem;
      border-radius: 3.5rem;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba($color: black, $alpha: 0.05);
      transition: all 0.5s;

      &[data-order='0'] {
        right: -17.5%;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: none;

      }
      &[data-order='1'] {
        right: -5.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='2'] {
        right: 6.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='3'] {
        right: 18.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='4'] {
        right: 30.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='5'] {
        right: 42.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='6'] {
        right: 54.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='7'] {
        right: 66.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='8'] {
        right: 78.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='9'] {
        right: 90.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='10'] {
        right: 102.5%;

      }
      &[data-order='11'] {
        right: 114.5%;
        display: none;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: none;

      }
      &--icon {
        color: #adadad;
        font-size: 7rem;
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
        transition: all 0.5s;

      }
      &--title {
        color: #adadad;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        font-weight: 400;


      }
      &--arrow {
        color: #4d48a8;
        font-size: 3rem;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-5rem);
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;

      }
    }
    .service__block:hover {
      .service__block--icon,
      .service__block--title {
        color: #707070;
      }
    }
    .selected {
      height: 250px;
      border: 1px solid #4d48a8;

      .service__block--title {
        color: #4d48a8;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;

      }
      .service__block--icon {
        color: #4d48a8;
      }
      .service__block--arrow {
        display: block;
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      &:hover {
        .service__block--title {
          color: #4d48a8;
        }
        .service__block--icon {
          color: #4d48a8;
        }
      }
    }
```

JS:

```
const serviceList = document.querySelectorAll('.service__block');

serviceList.forEach(service => {
  service.addEventListener('click', () => {
    markSelectedService(service);
    checkDistance(service);
    moveService(checkDistance(service));
  });
});

//Adds the class to the clicked service
function markSelectedService(service) {
  removeSelectedClass();
  service.classList.add('selected');
}

//Removes the selected class from all the services
function removeSelectedClass() {
  serviceList.forEach(service => {
    service.classList.remove('selected');
  });
}

function moveServices(service) {
  //Check Service distance from center
  checkDistance(service);
  //Check if service is outside view

  //Check last position of serviceList
  //If service is outside view disable display
  //Move service to end of the serviceList
  //Enable visiblity
}

//Check distance from center
function checkDistance(service) {
  let distance = service.dataset.order - 4;
  return distance;
}

//Check if service is outside view
//Services 1 to 9 are visible the rest are outside the view
function checkIfVisible() {
  serviceList.forEach(service => {
    if (
      parseInt(service.dataset.order) > 0 &&
      parseInt(service.dataset.order) < 11
    ) {
      service.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
      service.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

//Move the service 1 by 1 n times
function moveService(distance) {
  if (distance > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
      serviceList.forEach(service => {
        service.dataset.order = parseInt(service.dataset.order) - 1;

        if (
          parseInt(service.dataset.order) === 0 &&
          service.dataset.name == 'instagram'
        ) {
          service.dataset.order = 11;
          service.dataset.order = checkServiceListLastPosition();
        } else if (parseInt(service.dataset.order) === 0) {
          service.dataset.order = 11;
          service.dataset.order = checkServiceListLastPosition() + 1;
        }
      });
    }
  } else if (distance < 0) {
    distance = distance * -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
      serviceList.forEach(service => {
        service.dataset.order = parseInt(service.dataset.order) + 1;
      });
    }
  }
}

//Check last position
function checkServiceListLastPosition() {
  lastPosition = 0;
  serviceList.forEach(service => {
    if (
      parseInt(service.dataset.order) > lastPosition &&
      parseInt(service.dataset.order) !== 11
    ) {
      lastPosition = parseInt(service.dataset.order);
    }
  });
  console.log(lastPosition);
  return lastPosition;
}
```

Code pen for current state:
https://codepen.io/tomyshoam/pen/yLLLYyQ

Comment: A lot of code to grek there! The crux of the issue is disabling the transition css on the elements that are moving just before the move occurs. This will involve adding a class with some css resembling, say, `transition: none;`

Comment: @jonny i already have     transition:none;    on the first and the last item to disable the transition, but it still pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another css block above your current **.service__block** to override the transition behavior of your **data-order 1** block.

```
.service__block {
  &[data-order='1'] {
    right: -17.5%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```